# Error on setup config properties with Java/Selenium/TestNG/Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I tried best couldn't find a complete instructions on how to config a properties file with Maven,Testng.

Here are what I did and the exception I got:

1. from TestNG for suite, added

content of the config file:
user=testuser
password=pswd

2. pom.xml
       
           
               src/test/resources
               true
3. in code:
   @BeforeTest @Parameters(value = { "config-file" })
   public void initFramework(String configfile) throws Exception 
   {

   ```
       InputStream stream = Config.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       try {
           properties.load(stream); 
           String user = properties.getProperty("user");
           String password = properties.getProperty("password");
           System.out.println("\nGot User FirstName+LastName shows as:"+ user +"\n" + password + "===========");

       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           // You will have to take some action here...
       }
   ```

   }

Here is what I got when compile:

org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'config-file' is required by @Configuration on method initFramework but has not been marked @Optional or defined

Question:
I think I got all options mixed but really wanted a working way to read the parameter for Java/Selenium/TestNG/Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Properties CONFIG= new Properties();
FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("C://config.properties");
CONFIG.load(ip);
```

//Now simply read through property file:-

```
String user = CONFIG.getProperty("user");
String password = CONFIG.getProperty("password");
```

//To write property file:-

```
CONFIG.setProperty("user","newbie1");
CONFIG.setProperty("password","secret123");
```

Comment: that's super fast answer and it works! I would accept the answer. thanks a lot !

Comment: it would be nicer if there is any implementation in testing/Mavan way if there is any :-)